# Have you ever had a problem with the 10GB c:\ limit on Windows EC2 instances?

Tags: windows-server-2003, amazon-ec2

We have a large windows instance on EC2 that's only running IIS with the actual websites living on EBS.  Yesterday, we had IIS go into a tailspin because c:\ somehow filled up (when I found the issue, there was only 3MB left).

All the logs and virtual memory are stored on another drive, so I have no idea what caused it fill up.  Has anyone else ever had this issue with EC2 and if so, what steps did you take to resolve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to determine where your disk space is being used, I highly recommend a disk space viewer such as [Treesize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/index.shtml).

You'll be able to easily determine what's using your disk space.

Answer (score 0):

We tried to host a SQL server on the Amazon cloud.  10GB was a huge problem because windows and SQL patches and downloaded components took up too much space.  It was almost impossible to get SP3 for SQL 2005 plus a recent updater package.  We ended up having to remove other installer packages.  We had already moved our databases and the system databases off the C drive and onto EC2 storage.  There just wasn't enough room.

For Amazon, C is not expandable beyond 10GB.  This is very low for a server with extra software like SQL.  While it's technically possible to run a SQL server in Amazon's cloud, I would never want to trust my data to their cloud.  There were too many work arounds that we had to do to get things reasonably working.

For IIS, I would think logs and site files would be moved to EC2 and most of your problems would have been avoided.  Or, site files on EC2 with log files on the locally attached/volatile storage.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, if a database is going to reside in a cloud, a private dedicated cloud would be a better fit then a shared cloud such as this.